# Fullpage scroll to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Im trying scroll my fullpage to next section if mouseenter

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpages">
        <div id="fullpage-left">
            <div class="section current" style="background: url(/images/slide-left-1.jpg) left center;">

            </div>
            <div class="section" style="background: url(/images/slide-left-2.jpg) left center;">

            </div>
            <div class="section" style="background: url(/images/slide-left-3.jpg) left center;">

            </div>
            <div class='icon-scroll'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="fullpage-right">
            <div class="section current" style="background: url(/images/slide-right-1.jpg) right center;">

            </div>
            <div class="section" style="background: url(/images/slide-right-2.jpg) right center;">

            </div>
            <div class="section" style="background: url(/images/slide-right-3.jpg) right center;">

            </div>
            <div class='icon-scroll'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#fullpage-left").mouseenter(function() {
        if ($('#fullpage-left .current').next('#fullpage-left .section').length > 0) {
            var $next = $('#fullpage-left .current').next('#fullpage-left .section');
            var top = $next.offset().top;

            $('#fullpage-left .current').removeClass('current');

            $('#fullpage-left').animate({
              scrollTop: top     
            }, function () {
                   $next.addClass('current');
            });
        }
    });
```

Its work fine for only 2 section, next have only class current and no scrollto.
Can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you scrollTo the next section on mouseenter, how will you see the section you're on. I'm guess I'm not understanding your logic.

Comment: fullpage-left and fullpage-right have 100% height of viewport and overflow:hidden. here screenshot: http://prntscr.com/eyhv80 , mouseenter event only for testing, this is work only with 2 sections, dunno why this stop scroll after 2 section